# Android game loop: Draw / Update strategy (API 16+)

Tags: android, performance, graphics, hardware-acceleration, game-loop

Im working on an Android 2D Game (+ own simple engine) and try to figure out what is the best approach to schedule the drawing/updating mechanisms (API 16+) to get my game motions smooth.

Im using a custom view to make use of the [Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html). The SurfaceView implementations werent very convincing. I studied the [Android Graphics Architecture](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) which introduced the idea of using [Choreographer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html) to me, but i am not sure if it makes sense combined with my custom view and `postInvalidate()`. Note that `postInvalidate()` is always executed on the UI Thread.

Here are the different approaches i tried so far :

1. Update Thread (constantly running with ellapsedTimeInMillis for timing) + Draw Thread which calls `postInvalidate()` every 16ms (with `Thread.sleep(restFrameTime)`)
2. Update Thread (constantly running with ellapsedTimeInMillis for timing) + Draw Thread Looper with Handler and Custom View implementing `Choreographer.FrameCallback` which calls `doFrame()`, which calls `postInvalidate()`
3. Only one Thread for Updating and Drawing with`Choreographer.FrameCallback` and one state-update every frame with timing-information of `doFrame(long frameTimeNanos)`. Drawing with `postInvalidate()`.

Im struggling to find the best approach because the performance tracing (traceview, systrace, glTracing...) is hard to understand and also very different for different devices and settings(e.g. power-save-mode). I also considered using `postInvalidateOnAnimation()` but i thought its redundant already using `Choreographer.FrameCallback`

What is your opinon on that topic? What do you think is the best approach for a buttery smooth jank-free 60 FPS game performance for API 16+? Am i doing something entirely wrong? Its hard to find detailed instructions about the Choreographer implementation especially.